# SQL display only MAX of my COUNT() column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Have a query that shows this...

```
salesPersonId Total
------------- -----------
AB4           3
GT10          2
JB9           1
JS1           2
KT8           4
TC3           4
VG7           2
WC2           7

(8 row(s) affected)
```

My query is...

```
SELECT so.salesPersonId, COUNT(so.orderId) AS 'Total'
FROM salesOrder AS so

GROUP BY so.salesPersonId
GO
```

I wanted to do this...

```
SELECT so.salesPersonId, COUNT(so.orderId) AS 'Total'
FROM salesOrder AS so
WHERE MAX(COUNT(so.orderId))
GROUP BY so.salesPersonId
GO
```

This gives me an error, any ideas on how to show only the salesPersonId with the highest total?  Here being WC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (or a subquery) to get the breakdown and then select all entries in your CTE where their total is equal to max total (as there *may* be more than one):

```
;WITH TotalOrders
AS
    (
    SELECT so.salesPersonId, COUNT(so.orderId) AS 'Total'
    FROM salesOrder AS so
    GROUP BY so.salesPersonId
    )
SELECT *
FROM TotalOrders [TO]
WHERE [TO].Total = (SELECT MAX([TO].Total) FROM TotalOrders [TO])
```

Comment: Works great, the WITH TotalOrders AS is new to me. Is that some kind of shortcut?

Comment: @DDDD - it is a [`common table expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) - think of it as a subquery (or a temporary view) and you're more than 60% of the way there (a CTE can do a few things that are difficult to do in a subquery).

Comment: Thank you, I will be examining these CTE further. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH totalCount
AS
(
    SELECT so.salesPersonId, COUNT(so.orderId) AS 'Total'
    FROM salesOrder AS so
    GROUP BY so.salesPersonId
),
maxCount AS
(
    SELECT salesPersonId, Total,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Total DESC) rn
    FROM totalCount
)
SELECT salesPersonId, Total
FROM    maxCount
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: The DENSE_RANk gives me an error saying it takes exactly 0 arguments

Comment: try `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Total DESC) rn`